# Cree una tabla temporal, de lo cual inserte los registros de un sp y ocupo hacer una consulta pero tengo que relacionar 3 tablas

Tags: sql-server

--Creacion de tabla temporal que traiga SKU, URLImagenes, TipoImagen, Id del departamento solo 3 digitos IDPMM

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpArticulosImagenes(  
Id INT, 
IdRow INT,
SKU VARCHAR(10),
URLImagenes VARCHAR(MAX),
Directorio VARCHAR(MAX),
NombreImagen VARCHAR(MAX),
TipoImagen VARCHAR(200),
 );
```

-- Insertar los registros del SP

```
 Insert Into #tmpArticulosImagenes exec Sp_ArticuloImagenes_Exportar;
```

-- Ver los registros de la tabla temporal

```
select*from #tmpArticulosImagenes
```

--consulta

```
Select AR.SKU, AR.URLImagenes, AR.NombreImagen, AR.TipoImagen
from #tmpArticulosImagenes as AR 
join Articulo A on  CAST (AR.SKU  AS NVARCHAR(10)) = CAST(A.SKU AS NVARCHAR(10))
join Departamento d on A.IdDepartamento = d.ID
Where  AR.TipoImagen = 'Planogramas'
```

--ARROJA EL ERROR

--`**1.*Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.***--`

No se si tenga que ver con la relacion de la FK ya que es una tabla temporal, o sea que no estan relacionadas

Comment: Las columnas de la tabla temporal (que se crean en tempdb), y de la tabla contra la que haces el join, tienen diferente intercalación. Puedes igualar la misma, o en la creación de la tabla temporal, para la columna SKU o en el join, tal que join Articulo A on  `CAST (AR.SKU  AS NVARCHAR(10)) collation xxx = CAST(A.SKU AS NVARCHAR(10)) collation xxxx` donde las xxx, las sustituyes por la intercalación que tiene la Tabla. Que supongo que será SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS

Comment: MUCHAAS GRACIAAS!!